# How to make this type of onboarding screen that stores the data and has a different model in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[I have to implement this UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmpt6.jpg)

Please, anyone, I want to know if anyone has the idea of how to make this type of onboarding screen that stores the data and has a different model.

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), if you have not done so already. Also take a look at [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps

- You Can use Firebase to store the data (watch some basic tutorials first)
- Use Image picker(pub.dev) for picking images from phone's gallery
- and SS and crop out the complex components(images) from the given UI and use as asset image.